# How to grant all users/ online clients permission to specific folders in Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

When I enter my server ip on google, apache says 'Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /websockets/ on this server.'

I have tried the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/websockets   
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www/html/websockets  
sudo chmod -R 757 /var/www/html/websockets
```

However none seem to get rid of the error.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Note that making everything `777` is not recommended when using a productive server (for testing its possibly OK though). Check the other directories which are part of the path: What are the permissions for `/var`, `/var/www`, `/var/www/html` repsectively. Try to login as user `www-data` and check if `www-data` can read the files you are trying to access. Btw. I do not fully understand what's meant by "When I entry my server ip on google"?